# UITableview reload ends up with NSInternalInconsistencyException in Xamarin IOS/IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a sectional tableview in Xamarin IOS app . Each row can be tapped to expand or collapse. The rows can also be swipe deleted. Upon swipe deleting a row, a new row gets inserted at the bottom of that section.

This has been working fine when rows are in collapsed state. But when one of the row is in expanded state and I try to swipe delete a collapsed row, I get NSInternalInconsistencyException.

Upon investigation, I found that the exception occurs when I reload the table view section with the following code.

```
tableView.ReloadSections(NSIndexSet.FromIndex(indexPath.Section), UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
```

The complete code snippet for this is:

```
public override UITableViewRowAction[] EditActionsForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

            var actionHide = UITableViewRowAction.Create(UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default,
                                                         "Hide",  (arg1, arg2) =>
            {

            UserChallengeDisplayState activity = GroupedChallenge[indexPath.Section][indexPath.Row];
            NSIndexPath[] rows = new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath };

            // delete the row from the table source and UITableView

                //create the new indexpath to insert the placeholder activity
                int lastRowIndex = (int)(tableView.NumberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.Section) - 1);
                var newIndexPath = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(lastRowIndex, indexPath.Section);


                    GroupedChallenge[indexPath.Section].RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
                    tableView.DeleteRows(rows, UITableViewRowAnimation.Left);

                    //UITable view adds a placeholder cell when a cell is being deleted which has white background. 
                    //Adding this code to set background to clear color for the placeholder cell as it appears on top of the deleted cell
                    foreach (var subview in tableView.Subviews)
                    {
                        if (subview.Class.Name.ToString() == "_UISwipeToDeletePlaceholderCell")
                        {

                            subview.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                tableView.PerformBatchUpdates(() => 
                {
                    GroupedChallenge[indexPath.Section].Insert(lastRowIndex, new UserChallengeDisplayState(new UserChallenge() { HasFullData = false, Id = -10 }));
                    tableView.InsertRows(new NSIndexPath[] { newIndexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Right);  

                },
                (bool b) => 
                { 

                        // Reload section in order to prevent expand/collapse activity issue
                        tableView.ReloadSections(NSIndexSet.FromIndex(indexPath.Section), UITableViewRowAnimation.None);   




                    //Update UI with new recommendations
                    UpdateUIWithNewRecommendations(indexPath, activity.Challenge.HistoryTemplateID, tableView, FeedbackResponse.HideForNow);
                });


            });
            actionHide.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple;
            return new UITableViewRowAction[] { actionHide };
        }
        return new UITableViewRowAction[0];
    }
```

The complete exception details are below.

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Could not compute initial update value after shadow updates. Update: <UICollectionViewUpdateItem: 0x60800025f7d0> index path before update ((null)) index path after update (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) action (insert), Self: <_UIDataSourceUpdateMap: 0x60c00027abc0 intialSnapshot = [_UIDataSourceSnapshotter - 0x60c000a302e0:(0:3),(3:23)]; finalSnapshot = [_UIDataSourceSnapshotter - 0x60c00083dd40:(0:4),(4:23)]; updates = (
    "<UICollectionViewUpdateItem: 0x60c000442910> index path before update ((null)) index path after update (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) action (insert)"
)>, newBaseMap: <_UIDataSourceUpdateMap: 0x608000660c80 intialSnapshot = [_UIDataSourceSnapshotter - 0x60c000a302e0:(0:3),(3:23)]; finalSnapshot = [_UIDataSourceSnapshotter - 0x6080010313a0:(0:3),(3:23)]; updates = (
    "<UICollectionViewUpdateItem: 0x60800025ddf0> index path before update (<NSIndexPath: 0x608001823540> {length = 2, path = 0 - 9223372036854775807}) index path after update ((null)) action (delete)",
    "<UICollectionViewUpdateItem: 0x60800025e360> index path before update ((null)) index path after update (<NSIndexPath: 0x6080018273c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 9223372036854775807}) action (insert)"
)>
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f5fb1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011055b031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f600472 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010e93e652 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010c941fe5 -[_UIDataSourceUpdateMap rebasedMapFromNewBaseMap:] + 1485
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ca53589 -[_UITableViewShadowUpdatesController rebaseExistingShadowUpdatesForUpdates:] + 583
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010c802821 -[UITableView _rebaseExistingShadowUpdatesIfNecessaryWithItems:insertItems:deleteItems:sortedInsertItems:sortedDeleteItems:sortedMoveItems:] + 923
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c7fe3a3 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 4191
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c81bf0a -[UITableView _updateSections:withUpdateAction:rowAnimation:headerFooterOnly:usingPresentationValues:] + 970
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c81c37e -[UITableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:] + 140
    10  LimeadeMobile.iOS                   0x0000000108969ea9 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
    11  ???                                 0x0000000134a6ca91 0x0 + 5178313361
```

Comment: Try to use tableView.ReloadData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding tableview.ReloadData() fixed the issue.